# Where clause in update not working?

Tags: php, mysql

date function:

```
$date = "2017-02-02 09:00:00";  
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET `10` = 5 WHERE `date` = date($date)");
```

This query completes but nothing is added.

```
WHERE `date` = date($date1);  -- this part isn't working
```

I am trying to extract the date part from the `$date` and insert something in a row where that date is in a column named 'date'.

If I do it manually, like below, it works.

```
UPDATE table SET `10` = 5 WHERE `date` = '2017-02-02'
```

Comment: 1. stop using deprecated+removed `mysql_*` library, use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO` along with `prepared statement`. 2. Try once:- `mysql_query("UPDATE table SET 10 = 5 WHERE `date` = date('$date')");`3. also is this your column name`10`? very bad

Comment: what is your column datatype ? you save as date or either both date and time? and if the column name is `10` is it right?

Comment: What do you expect from your query ?,.. (this query should not update  the rows)  there is not a column 10

Comment: Yes column name is 10, it represents an action in 10th hour of the day. Datatype of the column 'date' is date. The query should update the value of a column named '10' in a row where column 'date' is the given date.
Thanks for answering, sorry for bad names :)

Comment: `$date` and `$date1` - so, which one is it?

Comment: *"Datatype of the column 'date' is date"* - change it to `datetime` and magic may happen when using `$date = "2017-02-02 09:00:00";`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's the missing quotes around `$date`, see example at [`date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date). Try changing it to

```
WHERE `date` = date('$date1')
```

Beyond that, you should get an error message somewhere in the webserver logs, or on standard error, if you run it on the command line.

Comment: Tried with the quotes already, not working. I'm checking the queries with 
if($query) and it returns true, but doesn't change the value in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1 = "02/02/2017 10:00:00";  
$dt = new DateTime($date1);
$date1 = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

I extracted the date like this. Then I used this date in MySQL without using the MySQL date function and it worked.